# Copying part of a directory structure to a new location

Tags: linux, command-line

I have a relatively large directory structure that is very consistent in its organization and I need to copy part of it to a new location.

Here's what I have:

```
./dev
    /man
        <.txt files>
    /other dir
    /another dir  
./mod
    /man
        <.txt files>
    /other dir
    /another dir
 ./blah
    /other dir
    /another dir
```

What I'm interested in are the .txt files in the man directory.  Some of the directories have /man/ and some don't, like ./blah above.

What I need to do is to reproduce the directory structure with the /man/ in a new location:

```
/opt/dev
    /man
        <.txt files>
/opt/mod
    /man
        <.txt files>
```

I've tried a number of different variations of find, rsync, cp, etc. and haven't found something that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me: `cp --parents ./*/man/*.txt /opt`

Comment: When I try that, I get the full directory tree, so each new directory has /home/user/blah/blah/blah/direcory of interest/*.txt.  I would like to get rid of /home/user/blah/blah/ for each one.

Comment: Maybe I'm not understanding, but just cd into /home/user/blah/blah/ first?

Comment: That did it.  I was executing outside /home/user/blah/blah/ when using cp --parents and getting the fully elaborated directory.  Thank you!