# Recursivly copy directory with a specific name to new location maintaining structure

Tags: bash, macos, copy, posix

Seems like this would have been addressed somewhere previously but I can't seem to find it.  Found this but `--parents` doesn't seem to work on MacOS.

[Copying part of a directory structure to a new location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25437345/copying-part-of-a-directory-structure-to-a-new-location)

I'm trying to copy a folder of a given name and it's contents to a new location maintaining the folder structure.

Example ... copy `results` from `src` to `dest`

```
src\ --
   folder1\ --
      file1.txt
      file2.txt
      file3.txt
      results\ --
         results1.txt
         results2.txt
   folder2\ --
      file1.txt
      file2.txt
      file3.txt
      results\ --
         results1.txt
         results2.txt
   folder3\ --
      file1.txt
      file2.txt
      file3.txt
      results\ --
         results1.txt
         results2.txt
```

I'd like to end up with this

```
dest\ --
   folder1\ --
      results\ --
         results1.txt
         results2.txt
   folder2\ --
      results\ --
         results1.txt
         results2.txt
   folder3\ --
      results\ --
         results1.txt
         results2.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're in the src directory and the dest folder exists, you can run the following to recursively copy all directories and subdirectories into dest. If dest doesn't exist, create it before running the loop.

```
for dir in *
do   
  if [ -d $dir ]
  then    
    mkdir ../dest/$dir
    for subdir in $dir/*
    do  
      if [ -d $subdir ]
      then      
        cp -r $subdir ../dest/$subdir
      fi     
    done
  fi
done
```

Comment: Wow .. .there's no easier way than to brute force this with a script?

Comment: Potentially the cp command has an option that you can you use but from what I can see, since you want all folders and some files this may be your best bet.

Answer (score 0):

On MacOS, which does not support `--parents` option of `cp` command, you will be able to use `ditto` command as an alternative.
Please try:

```
mkdir -p dest
cd src
find . -type d -mindepth 2 | xargs -I ditto {} ../dest
```

which will be equivalent to:

```
mkdir -p dest
cd src
find . -type d -mindepth 2 | xargs -I cp -a -P {} ../dest
```

if `--parents` or `-P` option is available.